# Overwrite TCP Connector in twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I have a HTTP proxy server written with Python's twisted framework to remove some limitations of most HTTP proxies, especially with faulty round robin DNS records, where one or more entries are offline, unreacheable or have no open port for the supplied protocol.

To do that, I would like to implement a cache that supplies my twisted stack with an IP that works so I can reduce timeout errors(and thus necessary retries) and other problems that are produced by these records.

Now I would like to replace the default `twisted.internet.tcp.Connector` that is used in the default implementation. I found out, that it is given as a parameter in `twisted.internet.protocol.ClientFactory.clientConnectionFailed()`, but did not find, where it is set up, so I could replace it.

How can I go about replacing the default Connector class with my own subclass and is there any documentation on this I missed?

**Edit:** It seems, [Glyph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32918852/1879299) points in the right direction. The question now would be, how to implement/inject the new Endpoint that resolves with my tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

You should never need to replace `Connector`.  It sounds like you want to use an [endpoint](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.4.0/core/howto/endpoints.html) and write one that does something more specific than [`HostnameEndpoint`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.4.0/api/twisted.internet.endpoints.HostnameEndpoint.html) with DNS.  But it would be more helpful if your question revealed more details about what *specifically* you were trying to do with faulty round-robin DNS records.

Comment: I've added some details on what I want to do. Not sure if this is possible though...

Comment: The way to "inject" the new endpoint is simply to instantiate it and then pass it to your code that needs an endpoint; no fancy footwork required.